# Cisco ASA 5505: switchport VLAN assignment

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vlan, switch

Kind of a Cisco Luddite, but I'd like to assign physical switchports 0/1 and 0/2 to Vlan2 and physical switchports 0/3 and 0/4 to Vlan3.  I'm assuming this is possible with base security license, i.e.:

```
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 100.200.100.200 255.255.255.
  no shutdown
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0

!
interface Vlan3
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.0

!
interface Ethernet0/0
  switchport access vlan 1
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 3
!
```

Comment: Yeah, that should work - though with the base license I think you'd need to have the traffic restriction where `dmz` can't initiate a connection to `inside`.  Is it coughing up an error when you try to put that config in?

Comment: I've not worked with an ASA but do you need to set "switchport mode access" on those ports?

Comment: I have not had a chance to play with it (it's in a data center right now), so I'm reaching out for a confident, resounding "yes" or "no" fellas :)

Comment: @joeqwerty from the live config, looks like it's just `switchport access vlan1` (right now, just `Ethernet0/1` is assigned to `Vlan2`; looking to add another port to each Vlan)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that'll work just fine, though the base license will force you to restrict one of the interfaces:

```
interface Vlan3
 no forward interface Vlan2
```

Comment: Confoosed by what you mean by "restrict one of the interfaces".

Comment: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa72/asdm52/user/guide/ifcs5505.html#wp1054656

Comment: They must have the Security Plus license because right now, the 3 Vlan interfaces are all active and can pass traffic between each other (with appropriate ACLs).